In maven pom file, how to exclude all classes except one in dependency
I have bcprov-jdk15on 1.47 version required to support only JcaJceHelper class..
How to exclude all other classes in this dependency except JcaJceHelper?
Using Excludes tag but not sure on its syntax

You can not exclude classes. You can exclude artifacts (more accurate jar files)

About the syntax the docs will help here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#how-to-use-dependency-exclusions
